# how to add a class in side a else condition on js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function check_empty() {
if (document.getElementById('CompanyName').value == "" || document.getElementById('ContactName').value == "" || document.getElementById('Address').value == "" || document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value == "" || document.getElementById('Email').value == ""){
alert("Fill All Fields !");
} else {
/*want to add a class="my" */
alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
}
}

/*html code*/
<a href="javascript:%20check_empty()" class="my">Submit to download</a>
```

when I click the link "Submit to download" "check_empty()" is called, if all filds are empty it will ask "Fill All Fields !" else I want to call a class "my", which is now on  element of html. How to add it on js?

Comment: What element do you want to add it too...? And it's not recommended you use Ids everywhere, uppercase Ids, javascript calls in an href, anchor element as submit button, mixture of single and double quotes for no reason, href instead of 'submit' event, double instead of triple equals etc.. so many bad practices in such a small amount of code!

Comment: `document.getElementById("CompanyName").className = "my"`

Comment: Actually `document.getElementById("CompanyName").classList.add('my');` is better since you are not overwriting existing classes

Comment: can you tell me what i can do to rectify my code? As i mentioned i want to add the class for else condition on anchor element

Comment: Oh yes @DominicTobias. Thanks. I assumed that he hasn't multiple classes.

Comment: @CHANDAN i think you are looking for placeholder, required, and autofocus check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

i think what you are looking for is how to use attr `placeholder`, `required`, and `autofocus` you don`t need javascript to check if the inputs are empty try this:

```html
<form>
    <input id=CompanyName type=text placeholder=CompanyName required autofocus />
    <input id=ContactName type=text placeholder=ContactName required />
    <input id=Address type=text placeholder=Address required />
    <input id=PhoneNumber type=text placeholder=PhoneNumber required />
    <input id=Email type=text placeholder=Email required />
    <input type=submit value=send />
</form>
```

Now you can do something when the form is ready

```js
function sendMyForm(event){
    alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
}

var sendForm = document.querySelector("form");

sendForm.addEventListener("submit", sendMyForm, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input id=CompanyName type=text placeholder=CompanyName required autofocus />
    <input id=ContactName type=text placeholder=ContactName required />
    <input id=Address type=text placeholder=Address required />
    <input id=PhoneNumber type=text placeholder=PhoneNumber required />
    <input id=Email type=text placeholder=Email required />
    <input type=submit value=send />
</form>
```

Use `classList`

```
 document.querySelector("#CompanyName").classList.add('my');
```

so Your code could look like this

```
function check_empty() {
   if (document.getElementById('CompanyName').value == "" || document.getElementById('ContactName').value == "" || document.getElementById('Address').value == "" || document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value == "" || document.getElementById('Email').value == ""){
      alert("Fill All Fields !");
   } else {
      /*want to add a class="my" */
      document.querySelector("#CompanyName").classList.add('my');
      /*document.getElementById("CompanyName").classList.add('my')*/
      alert("Form Submitted Successfully...");
   }
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#CompanyName")` is the same as `document.getElementById("CompanyName")`

Comment: @Tambo then why use `.querySelector()`? (`.getElementById()` is **much** faster.)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")` and then iterate.

Comment: @George because it is more flexible you can select more than one class or id, and you can you want ever you want inside.

Comment: @abhitalks you can use `var textInputArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]"));` to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to call two javascript functions on a single click::

If so.. try this...

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onClick="return check_empty() ? my() : false"> Submit to download </a>
```

Comment: Am just calling two functions when "onclick" is clicked... one is check_empty() and the other is "my()"... and false means to "return false"